# Getting the author and the date of last commit for all the files in a git repo

Tags: git, commit, git-log

I have a large repo with many documents (it is an ADO Wiki repo). I want to get the author and the last updated date of each of the documents in the repo. Currently, I'm running

```
git log -1 --pretty=format:%ci, %cn -- <file path>
```

for every file in the repo but this is very slow and takes a long time to finish. What is a faster way to get what I need?

Update:

I modified the accepted answer to get the earliest commit date (the creation date) and all the authors of the file:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

declare -A seen_latest seen_earliest authors

while read -r line ; do
    if [[ $line = /* ]] ; then
        hash=${line%% *}
        date=${line#* }
        date=${date:0:25}
        committer=${line#* }
        committer=${committer:26}
    elif [[ $line && -z ${seen_latest[$line]} ]] ; then
        seen_latest[$line]="$date|$committer"
    fi
    if [[ $line ]] ; then
        if [[ -z ${authors[$line]} ]] ; then
            authors[$line]="$committer"
        elif [[ ! "${authors[$line]}" =~ "$committer" ]] ; then
            authors[$line]="${authors[$line]}:$committer" # you can use any other separators you like
        fi
        seen_earliest[$line]="$date|$committer"
    fi
done < <(git log --format='/%H %ci %cn' --name-only)

find -name .git -prune -or -print | while read f ; do
    f=${f#./}
    printf '%s|%s|%s|%s\n' "$f" "${seen_latest[$f]}" "${seen_earliest[$f]}" "${authors[$f]}"
done
```

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that unless the files were always modified on the wiki server directly, the last commit date does not necessarily represent when the published file changed. Commits could be authored anywhere, and then the actual published changed would probably be the time the commit was pushed and/or merged to the branch that serves the wiki.

Comment: @TTT that’s a good point but in this specific case, there is only one master branch and all the changes are committed directly to master so the commit date represents the last update date of the wiki. But for other use cases, that’s definitely something to be aware of

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of walking the files, walk the log. For each file, remember the committer and the last time of modification. Then, walk the files and print the remembered information.

The following works when there are no weird file names in the repository (no newlines in file names etc.):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
declare -A seen
while read -r line ; do
    if [[ $line = /* ]] ; then
        hash=${line%% *}

        date=${line#* }
        date=${date:0:25}

        committer=${line#* }
        committer=${committer:26}

    elif [[ $line && -z ${seen[$line]} ]] ; then
        seen[$line]="$date, $committer"
    fi
done < <(git log --format='/%H %ci %cn' --name-only)

find -name .git -prune -or -print | while read f ; do
    f=${f#./}
    printf '%s: %s\n' "$f" "${seen[$f]}"
done
```

On a repository of 468 files and 558 commits, the processing takes about 0.07s, while walking the files and asking `git log` for each takes about 11.5s.

Comment: This seems to work pretty fine thank you. What's happening here is that you get the logs only once and then loop through them, add the commit of the file to an array called `seen` only once (you loop through the commits in the first if block and update the variables) and at the end when you `seen` array is created and has the info for each file, you print the results. is that right?

Comment: and it is of course much faster because there is only one `git log` in the script

Comment: Exactly. If you don't care about deleted files being reported, you can output the line directly when populating $seen and you can skip the `find`.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit of `awk` should help:

```
git log --name-only --pretty='format:info:%ci, %cn' | awk '
/^info:/ { info=$0; next }
$0 && !files[$0]++ { print $0, substr(info,6) }'
```

It keeps a list of all previously-seen files and only outputs each file once with the commit date and author.

First few lines of output for the git.git repository:

```
Documentation/RelNotes/2.40.0.txt 2023-02-15 17:11:54 -0800, Junio C Hamano
Documentation/RelNotes/2.39.3.txt 2023-02-14 14:15:57 -0800, Junio C Hamano
GIT-VERSION-GEN 2023-02-14 14:15:57 -0800, Junio C Hamano
RelNotes 2023-02-14 14:15:57 -0800, Junio C Hamano
t/t4018/java-non-sealed 2023-02-08 12:57:13 -0800, Junio C Hamano
t/t4018/java-sealed 2023-02-08 12:57:13 -0800, Junio C Hamano
t/t4018/java-sealed-permits 2023-02-08 12:57:13 -0800, Junio C Hamano
t/t4018/java-sealed-type-parameters 2023-02-08 12:57:13 -0800, Junio C Hamano
t/t4018/java-sealed-type-parameters-implements-permits 2023-02-08 12:57:13 -0800, Junio C Hamano
t/t4018/java-sealed-type-parameters-permits 2023-02-08 12:57:13 -0800, Junio C Hamano
```

Generating the complete output for this repository takes approximately 5 seconds on my system (69410 commits, 4324 files in HEAD; 5558 total distinct files in history).